# how to replay service broker messages : Poison Message handling

Tags: service-broker

Am using SQL Server Service Broker 2012.Am capturing the messages in the ServiceBrokerError table if there is any error while processing the Service Broker message.Now how can i reprocess the updated service broker message?

Comment: What do you mean saying 'updated service broker message'? Message can be sent or received. Send message again and it will be processed while receiving by target. Is it not your situation?

Comment: While processing a message i got a error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column" and that message i want to re send the message again but using the same conversation handle".can i set the conversation handle variable and send the same message again?

Comment: I think that you have so called Poison Message. Handling such messages described [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171592.aspx) or in [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2309/sql-server-service-broker-poison-message-handling/)

Comment: Sorry for late response but the link you provided resolved my problem and gave some good knowledge on the Poison messages.Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Happy that it helped. Maybe it's useful to update your question referencing problem to poison messages, so visitors could find answer faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below links helped me in resolving my actual Poison Message handling problem.As suggested By Serg

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171592.aspx,

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2309/sql-server-service-broker-poison-message-handling/

Thanks,

Ravi